# (Nautilus Scripts) $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; have problems with space

Tags: bash, nautilus-script

So the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
   if [[ "$line" = "" || "$line" = " " ]]; then
      exit
   else
      unzip "$line" -d "temp"
   fi
done
```

It works well and unzips the file. But if the file is named with a space (eg: Leon - 1994.zip) it will not work and the `$line` will be

1st time: /home/citybong/Downloads/Leon

2nd time: -

3rd time: 1994.zip

Edit: I fount a link http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/faq.php for the question: "My script can't handle multiple files/files with spaces" but i am kinda newbie to bash scripting and i can't understand their solutions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IFS is by default set to space, that's why your string is being divided into spaces. Just set it to the newline with the following code:

```
IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS="
"

for line in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do
    whatever $line
done

IFS=$IFS_BAK
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Caja in Ubuntu Mate 14.04

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to mess with IFS:

```
echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | while read filename; do
    unzip "$filename" -d temp
done
```

I had a similar problem and it turns out that echo preserves newlines in double quotes, but without quotes changes them to spaces.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer

Comment: Doesn't work in Caja of ubuntu mate 14.04

Comment: Worked for me in plain Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 0):

Using `$@` instead of `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` in Nautilus scripts could solve the problem with new line separators (which are used as delimiters in `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` and `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS`).

So, the code will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in "$@"; do
   if [[ "$line" = "" || "$line" = " " ]]; then
      exit
   else
      unzip "$line" -d "temp"
   fi
done
```

Also, this is handy when we need just pass selection to another app:

```
#!/bin/sh

baobab "$@"
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Caja in ubuntu mate 14.04

Answer (score -2):

Put single quotes around the variable name, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in '$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS'; do
   if [[ "$line" = "" || "$line" = " " ]]; then
      exit
   else
      unzip "$line" -d "temp"
   fi
done
```

Comment: $line becomes $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

Comment: Try double quotes then - I may have the wrong type listed in my response.

Comment: Xmm with double quotes the $line takes the fullpath of the file but with a new empty line, so the unzipping fails. line = $(echo $line | tr '\n') didn't help. Hakermanias solution solves the problem ;)